# Labels not showing when detecting objects with YOLO-NAS model on video

Tags: python

I have trained a yolonas model with custom dataset and saved best.pth.now when I am loading the best model and trying to  detect objects in a video,the labels are not showing.I don't understand whats the problem.

```
cap=cv2.VideoCapture('/Users/anika/PycharmProjects/ml_projects/test.mp4')
frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
frame_height = int(cap.get(4))

device = 0 if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('l.mp4',fourcc, 200, (frame_width,frame_height))

# out = cv2.VideoWriter("detection.mp4",cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'),12,(frame_width,frame_height),True)
count = 0
while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    count +=1
    if ret:
        result = list(best_model.to(device).predict(frame))[0]
        bbox_xyxys = result.prediction.bboxes_xyxy.tolist()
        confidences = result.prediction.confidence
        labels = result.prediction.labels.tolist()
        for (bbox_xyxy, confidence,cls) in zip(bbox_xyxys,confidences,labels):
            bbox = np.array(bbox_xyxy)
            class_names = dataset_params['classes']
            x1,y1,x2,y2 = bbox[0], bbox[1], bbox[2], bbox[3]
            print(x1)
            x1,y1,x2,y2 = int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2)
            cv2.rectangle(frame,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,144,30),3)
        out.write(frame)
        # cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('1'):
            break
    else:
        break
out.release()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here's my code snippet. The video has been saved as `l.mp4`, but the objects have not been detected. I mean bounding boxes and labels are not showing

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is extend the functionality of your code.

You can't see any labels because, after receiving the confidence score and labels from the Yolo NAS model, you have not instructed openCV to utilize those labels.

You may use [cv2.getTextSize()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga3d2abfcb995fd2db908c8288199dba82) to determine how many pixels the label will take up and then use it to specify the rectangle width before using [cv2.putText()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga5126f47f883d730f633d74f07456c576) to overlay text information on top of a rectangle.

## Check out the code below.

```
while (cap.isOpened()):
ret, frame = cap.read()
frame_count += 1

if ret:
    result = list(model.to(device).predict(frame, conf = 0.75))[0]

    # get  bounding box coordinates. confidence, labels

    # bounding box coordinates
    bbox_xyxy_cord = result.prediction.bboxes_xyxy.tolist()

    # confidence score
    confidence_score = result.prediction.confidence

    # label
    class_labels = result.prediction.labels.tolist()

    for (bbox_xyxy, confidence, cls) in zip(bbox_xyxy_cord, confidence_score, class_labels):
        bbox = np.array(bbox_xyxy)
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = bbox[0], bbox[1], bbox[2], bbox[3]
        # print("Frame Count: ", frame_count, "coordinates: " , x1, y1, x2, y2)

        # convert to integer
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2)
        print("Frame Count: ", frame_count, "coordinates: ", x1, y1, x2, y2)

        # confidence
        conf = math.ceil((confidence * 100)) / 100

        # label
        class_integer = int(cls)
        # class_integer = 0 -> mask_worn_incorrect ,1 -> 'with_mask', 2 - > 'without_mask
        cls_name = class_names[class_integer]

        # combine class name and confidence score
        label = f'{cls_name}{","}{conf}'
        print(label)

        # text size of label
        font = 0
        fontScale = 0.6
        thickness = 1
        # t_size, _ = cv2.getTextSize('Test', font, fontScale, thickness)
        t_size = cv2.getTextSize(label, font, fontScale, thickness)[0]
        weight_height = x1 + t_size[0] , y1 - t_size[1] - 3

        # display the label box and confidence
        # label and confidence score
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), weight_height, [255, 0, 255], -1, cv2.LINE_AA) # filled
        cv2.putText(frame, label, (x1, y1 - 2), 0, 0.6, [0, 0, 0], thickness = 1, lineType = cv2.LINE_AA)
        # bounding box
        bb_box_color = (255, 255, 255)
        bb_box_thickness = 1
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), bb_box_color, bb_box_thickness)

    out.write(frame)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('1'):
        break
else:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

In the GitHub issue section, a user has reported that bounding boxes do not appear in the prediction process after training. Editors have labeled this issue as a "bug."
For detailed information, please click link below.

[No Bounding Boxes being plotted when doing inference on an image (Loading Trained Weights from Checkpoint)](https://github.com/Deci-AI/super-gradients/issues/1266)

Additionally, on the official website, it has been mentioned that prediction and inference processes are supported, but the training process is not. Link: [YOLO-NAS (Neural Architecture Search)](https://docs.ultralytics.com/models/yolo-nas/#supported-tasks)